# How instantiate a typeorm entity with values without db connection?

Tags: typeorm

I did this UserFactory:

```
export class UserFactory {
    create(values = {}): User {
        return User.create({
            // defaults
            name: 'Jerry',
            age: 99,
            // overrides
            ...values,
        })
    }
}
```

It is my understanding that `Entity.create` does *not* persist the entity in my db, it only creates the instance (I'm using the BaseEntity/ORM pattern). This is precisely what I want. However, it still requires a connection to work. In my tests I need to do something like:

```
const connection = await db()
const user = new UserFactory().create()
await connection.destroy()
```

Otherwise, I get `DataSource is not set for this entity`. I can't understand why a connection is needed when it's not even saving it.

I guess I could use `new User()` but unfortunately there is no `set` methods to bulk apply my `values` then.

How can I set my values and get an entity instance without unnecessary db connections here?